# Calculating probability using simulation

Tags: r, random, statistics, simulation, probability

Let Xi~U(0,30) be random variables. If one takes a sample of n=12, then we are interested in knowing the probability of the proportion to be greater than 18 i.e. $P(\overline X_{12}>18)$

Without using simulation and applied the CLT, the answer is .1150

Here is my approach to implement this in R using simulation:

```
SimProb<-function(N)
{
n=12

M<-matrix(runif(1,0,30),N,n)
rowMeann<-rowMeans(M)

for(i in 1:N)
{
  if(rowMeann[i]>18)
    c=cumsum(rowMeann[i])
    c

}
prob<-1-c
return(prob)
}
```

The code does not show any error but does not work properly.

When I was checking, it turns out `c= 6.083532` which can't be.

For different values of `N`, `SimProb` returns only negative values, I don't understand why.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step solution.

1. To generate a single sample we may use `runif(12, 0, 30)`.
2. The corresponding sample mean then is `mean(runif(12, 0, 30))`.
3. As to estimate the true probability, we need to simulate many instances like that, which can be done with, e.g.

```
replicate(mean(runif(12, 0, 30)), n = 10000)
```

4. Then we want to find (number of times `mean(runif(12, 0, 30))` is greater than 18) / 10000, which can be done with

```
set.seed(1)
mean(replicate(mean(runif(12, 0, 30)), n = 10000) > 18)
# [1] 0.1163
```

which is indeed very close to your provided value.

Comment: Why changing the uniform distribution to beta distribution this does not work anymore? I tried `replicate(mean(rbeta(12,2,5)), n = 10000)
set.seed(1)
mean(replicate(mean(rbeta(12,2,5)), n = 10000) > 18)` and the output is `0`

Comment: @Isa, because beta distribution has values in [0,1]. An average of 12 values then is never going to exceed 18.